# Custom function output in rows instead of columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

The following script returns the values from the for loop in rows. Is there anyway to return the results into the adjacent columns instead?

```js
function readMessage(msgId){
  var url = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/mailbox/mailThreads/";
  var token = "/mailMessages?api_token=token";
  Logger.log("readMessage called with msgId: " + msgId);
  if (msgId){ // make sure there is a msgId in the cell 
    var rows = [] 
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+msgId+token); 
    var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
    var dataSet = dataAll;

    var rows = [], data;

    for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.data.length; i++) {
      data = dataSet.data[i];

      rows.push([data.body_url]);
    } 

    Logger.log( JSON.stringify(rows,null,2) ); 

    return rows;
  }
```

Current output is-

```
   A                  B    C    D
1 =readMessage(msgId)
2 "blah blah"
3 "blah blah"
```

What I want is-

```
   A                       B            C          D
1 =readMessage(msgId) "blah blah"  "blah blah"
2 
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Google Apps Script data is always in the form of a 2D array. It's helpful to have visualization.

```
    A   B   C
1 [[A1, B1, C1],
2 [A2, B2, C2]]
```

in order to return a row of data the function should return

```
[[A,B,C]] // 3 columns of data in one row
```

in order to return a column of data you can use either the full 2D array or a single array

```
[[1],[2],[3]]
OR
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: what about when we need to expand both rows and columns with a custom function? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the formatting of the data you are returning. Try this `rows.push(data.body_url);` instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.data.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet.data[i];

    rows.push(data.body_url); //Brackets [] have been removed to insert data as a row.
}
```

If you return data like this: `[[1],[3],[6]]` the result will be a column of values:

1

3

6

If you data has this format: `[2,4,8]` you get a row of values:

2  |  4  |  6

Source: [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#arguments)